# high cpu usage : scsi_eh_1

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora, disk

This process, scsi_eh_1, is using more than 60% of the CPU

fedora
6.5.5-200.fc38

I updated Linux a few days ago, but I don't think the updates are related to this issue!
The command 'is-system-running' also shows 'running' and apparently there is no problem!

Comment: eh is error handler. Check your logs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had completely forgotten to check the logs. The problem was that the iscsi.service was not starting. I searched a lot but didn't find a solution.

Comment: iscsi.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.                                       iscsi.service - Login and scanning of iSCSI devices was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=/var/lib/iscsi/nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using vmware? I also saw cpu on scsi_eh_1 constantly between 40-80% after update of [ArchBang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArchBang) inside Vmware Workstation Player. My attempts at `sudo kill -9 <PID>` was futile. Kernel 6.5.5 as viewed by `uname -r`.

I mitigated by removing the CD/DVD drive since I only rarely need access to that/an .iso file:

When opening Vmware I pressed the button "Edit virtual machine settings". Then chose device "CD/DVD Drive". Then "-Remove". It can easily be added back later with the "+Add" button. This is of course not a solution, but works for  the time being.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to add New Device SATA controller to VM and then reattach CD/DVD drive to it instead of IDE 1 controller...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Kjetil and user22677375 had the right idea: the problem is having a CD/DVD (IDE) device in VMWare. You don't have to remove it, though. You can click on the device while the image is not running, click Advanced, and then check the SATA switch under Virtual device node instead of IDE.